# How to copy tfs groups and permissions from one team project to other in tfs 2015 ?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, team-project

Is there any way to copy TFS AD groups from one team project to other team project in TFS 2015 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot copy the groups with the permission settings.

You just need to add the groups to the new team project, them set the permission again.

See below related documents:

- [Set up groups for use in TFS deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/setup-ad-groups)
- [Add users to a team project or specific team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/add-users-team-project#add-users-or-groups-to-an-access-level-tfs-only)
- [Permissions and groups in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions)